# HttpContext.Session in Blazor Server Application

Tags: asp.net-core, session, httpcontext, blazor-server-side

I am trying to use `HttpContext.Session` in my ASP.NET Core Blazor Server application (as described in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1), I mean: all correctly set up in startup)

Here is the code part when I try to set a value:

```
var session = _contextAccessor.HttpContext?.Session;
if (session != null && session.IsAvailable)
{
    session.Set(key, data);
    await session.CommitAsync();
}
```

When this code called in Razor component's `OnAfterRenderAsync` the `session.Set` throws following exception:

> The session cannot be established after the response has started.

I (probably) understand the message, but this renders the Session infrastructure pretty unusable: the application needs to access **its state** in every phase of the execution...

**Question**

Should I forget completely the `DistributedSession` infrastructure, and go for Cookies, or Browser SessionStorage? ...or is there a workaround here still utilizing `HttpContext.Session`? I would not want to just drop the distributed session infra for a way lower level implementation...

(just for the record: Browser's Session Storage is NOT across tabs, which is a pain)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Blazor is fundamentally incompatible with the concept of traditional server-side sessions, especially in the client-side or WebAssembly hosting model where there is no server-side to begin with. Even in the "server-side" hosting model, though, communication with the server is over websockets. There's only one initial request. Server-side sessions require a cookie which must be sent to the client when the session is established, which means the *only* point you could do that is on the first load. Afterwards, there's no further requests, and thus no opportunity to establish a session.

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-3.1#where-to-persist-state) give guidance on how to maintain state in a Blazor app. For the closest thing to traditional server-side sessions, you're looking at using the browser's `sessionStorage`.

Comment: Thx, Yes I've already read that doc. My question: If we serialize some session state and store in the browser (preferably encrypted) then why would we use sessionStorage, instead a session cookie? Browser session storage is not across the tabs, which is expected. Syncing (two ways!) the sessionStorage is impossible correctly. Is there any benefit of session storage?

Answer (score 2):

Note: I know this answer is a little old, but I use sessions with WebSockets just fine, and I wanted to share my findings.

### Answer

I think this `Session.Set()` error that you're describing is a bug, since `Session.Get()` works just fine even after the response has started, but `Session.Set()` doesn't. Regardless, the workaround (or "hack" if you will) includes making a throwaway call to `Session.Set()` to "prime" the session for future writing. Just find a line of code in your application where you KNOW the response hasn't sent, and insert a throwaway call to `Session.Set()` there. Then you will be able to make subsequent calls to `Session.Set()` with no error, including ones after the response has started, inside your `OnInitializedAsync()` method. You can check if the response is started by checking the property `HttpContext.Response.HasStarted`.

Try adding this `app.Use()` snippet into your Startup.cs `Configure()` method. Try to ensure the line is placed somewhere before `app.UseRouting()`:

```
...
...
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

//begin Set() hack
app.Use(async delegate (HttpContext Context, Func<Task> Next)
{
    //this throwaway session variable will "prime" the Set() method
    //to allow it to be called after the response has started
    var TempKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); //create a random key
    Context.Session.Set(TempKey, Array.Empty<byte>()); //set the throwaway session variable
    Context.Session.Remove(TempKey); //remove the throwaway session variable
    await Next(); //continue on with the request
});
//end Set() hack

app.UseRouting();


app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
});
...
...
```

### Background Info

The info I can share here is not Blazor specific, but will help you pinpoint what's happening in your setup, as I've come across the same error myself. The error occurs when **BOTH** of the following criteria are met simultaneously:

**Criteria 1.** A request is sent to the server with no session cookie, or the included session cookie is invalid/expired.

**Criteria 2.** The request in Criteria 1 makes a call to `Session.Set()` after the response has started. In other words, if the property `HttpContext.Response.HasStarted` is **true**, and `Session.Set()` is called, the exception will be thrown.

**Important: If Criteria 1 is not met, then calling `Session.Set()` after the response has started will NOT cause the error.**

That is why the error only seems to happen upon first load of a page--it's because often in first loads, there is no session cookie that the server can use (or the one that was provided is invalid or too old), and the server has to spin up a new session data store (I don't know why it has to spin up a new one for Set(), that's why I say I think this is a bug). If the server has to spin up a new session data store, it does so upon the first call to `Session.Set()`, and new session data stores **cannot** be spun up after the response has started. On the other hand, if the session cookie provided was a valid one, then no new data store needs to be spun up, and thus you can call `Session.Set()` anytime you want, including after the response has started.

What you need to do, is make a preliminary call to `Session.Set()` before the response gets started, so that the session data store gets spun up, and then your call to `Session.Set()` won't cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

1. SessionStorege has more space than cookies.
2. Syncing (two ways!) the sessionStorage is impossible correctly
   I think you are thinking that if it is on the browser, how can you access that in C#? Please see some examples. It actually read from the browser and transfers (use) on the server side.
3. sessionstorage and localstorage in blazor are encrypted. We do not need to do extra for encryption. The same applies for serialization.