# Session In Razor View

Tags: session, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-middleware

Does anyone know how to set the `Session` in Razor View in ASP.NET Core? And how to get that value in a controller or anywhere else?

```cs
// set the session in controller like that:
HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserId", signInResponse.Id.ToString());

// Get the Value of Session anywhere
HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserId", signInResponse.Id.ToString());
```

This is working in classes but I don't know how to set and get it in Razor views in ASP.NET Core!

If anyone knows, please tell me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HttpContext.Session in Blazor Server Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61505915/httpcontext-session-in-blazor-server-application)

Answer (score 0):

Razor views in the MVC pattern expose the `HttpContext` via the `RazorPage.Context` property on the view.

So if you wanna set/get session in razor view, You can just use:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
    //set session
    Context.Session.SetString("MySession", "xxxxxxx");
    //get session
    var result = Context.Session.GetString("A");
}
```

Now you have set/get session in razor view successfully. Just use the code you provided in question to achieve it's value in controller.

More information please refer to [Access HttpContext in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-7.0#access-httpcontext-from-a-razor-view-in-mvc)

Comment: Hi @Web_Dev Haseeb, Have you solved this issue now?